# Force ./configure NOT to look in /usr/lib /usr/bin /usr/include

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg

I want to compile FFmpeg but as you know its compile will (by default) look in the system's 'lib include bin' directories before following my orders set via --extra-cflags or --extra-ldflags Now the system directory has for instance faac, x264, vpx....which I don't want to modify simply because thy are interlinked with many other application such as firefox, skype, totem, vlc...& by removing them I will remove every dependent application so is there any way (flag) that I pass on to the ./compile such that it don't look at system directories only to the directories I specify myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile any external libraries used as ffmpeg dependencies, such as x264 and libvpx (if you don't want to use the `-dev` versions from the repository), using a custom `--prefix`, and may need to use additional options. See `./configure --help` for options specific to each library. Then compile ffmpeg telling it where the external libraries are and where you want to install it. See some examples in this thread:

[[FFmpeg-user] Compiling ffmpeg with --prefix option](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-August/008553.html)

Comment: But I have done that already..For instance libfacc installed system wide is of older version & the newer .tar.gz I have downloaded & compiled say in /opt will be neglected while I compile ffmpeg because it 'preferably' will look into /usr/bin thus  will be compiled with the older version! Now if I remove that older version I will loose vlc,openshot & what not

Comment: @nightcrawler Your configure lines for your external libraries and ffmpeg would be useful.

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/opt/x264_ttmod --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaac -enable-libopencore --enable-shared --disable-static --extra-cflags=-L/opt/x264_ttmod/lib/ --extra-cflags=-I/opt/x264_ttmod/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/x264_ttmod/lib/ --extra-ldflags=-I/opt/x264_ttmod/include/` Dependant & new codecs were installed prior via `./configure --prefix=/opt/x264_ttmod --enable-shared && sudo make && sudo make install`

Comment: @nightcrawler It would have been easier to read as an update to your question instead of a comment and I almost mentioned that in my previous comment but thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: Don't give up just tell me the flags that I have to pass to ./configure to make it blind towards /usr/...